# Block in main.async only executes after a global.async block has finished

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, grand-central-dispatch

I'm calling a function from my library which should update some UI in the app:

```
DispatchQueue.global().async {
    autoreleasepool {
        print("is main thread =", Thread.isMainThread)
        for i in 0..<data.count {
            for j in 0..<data[i].createArray.count {
                let dataObject = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: entity, into: context)

                // Parse the dictionary of keys/values returned from the synced array into an easily readable JSON file.
                let parsedData = json(from: data[i].createArray[j])
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    label?.text = "Syncing " + String(describing: j + 1) + " " + entity + "s out of " + String(describing: data[i].createArray.count)
                    print("is main thread =", Thread.isMainThread)

                    print(label?.text)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, the block inside the main.async call only executes once the rest of the function has ran through. How can I change this to update with every iteration of the loop?

Comment: possibly with the use of `defer` statements or moving `main.async` to a separate function with parameters needed from the for loop that you are executing in `main.async`

Answer (score -1):

Instead of

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {}
```

use

```
DispatchQueue.main.sync {}
```